# Is accessing foreign key ID field directly faster in Django?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, mysql-python

Please reference these example models:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Team(models.Model):
    captain = models.ForeignKey(Manager, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.CharField()

class Manager(models.Model):
    networth = models.FloatField()
```

I am trying to figure out if the following is faster than the alternative (ie. accesses the database less):

```
team = Team.objects.get()
Player.objects.filter(team_id=team.id)
```

Alternative:

```
team = Team.objects.get()
Player.objects.filter(team=team)
```

Comment: It will result in the *same* query. Except for a few cycles that Django spends on inspecting what you passed and accessing the primary key, it does not make any difference.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so then it comes down to legibility, you would suggest the latter?

Comment: I would use `team.player_set.all()`, but that is if course more a "taste".

Comment: The real optimization here is to not get the team, but filter the player on the team arguments: `Player.objects.filter(team__name="Da Players")`, but if you need team as an object anyway, see Willem's answer.

Comment: @Melvyn interesting, why would filtering for team__name be faster than an ID query?

Comment: It wouldn't. I'm saying that you save a query if you don't need the team object, but have the name of the team (via form / query / kwarg). So instead of doing Team = ... Player.objects.filter() , you only do Player.objects.fitler().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to figure out if the following is faster than the alternative

**No**. It will result in the *same* query. Except for a few cycles that Django spends on inspecting what you passed and accessing the primary key, it does not make any difference.

You can inspect this in The Django shell with:

```
>>> print(Player.objects.filter(team_id=team.id).query)
SELECT `app_name_player`.`id`, `app_name_player`.`team_id` FROM `app_name_player` WHERE `app_name_player`.`team_id` = 1
>>> print(Player.objects.filter(team=team).query)
SELECT `app_name_player`.`id`, `app_name_player`.`team_id` FROM `app_name_player` WHERE `app_name_player`.`team_id` = 1
```

So the two queries are identical. Probably it is more idiomatic to fetch these with:

```
team.player_set.all()
```

If you need to access the `Player`s of a set of `Team`s, you can make use of [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to fetch all the `Player`s for a *set* of teams in one query, avoiding the *N+1* problem:

```
teams = Team.objects.prefetch_related('player_set')
```

Here if you then iterate over the `teams`, and fetch the `player_set` of each `Team` object, it will not make extra queries, since it has already fetched all the related `Player`s in one extra query, and did the "joining" at the Python/Django layer.

Answer (score 1):

So to illustrate my point in the comments better - what I see often in the wild is url structures like this:

`/teams/<int:pk>/players/`

Accompanied by view code like this:

```py
def players_view(request, pk):
    team = Team.objects.get(pk=pk)
    context = {
        "players": Player.objects.filter(team=team)
    }
    ...
```

while you can just do:

```py
def players_view(request, pk):
    context = {
        "players": Player.objects.filter(team__pk=pk)
    }
    ...
```

And extra points for:

```py
def players_view(request, pk):
    context = {
        "players": Player.objects.filter(team__pk=pk).select_related("team")
    }
    ...
```

And the template trick:

```html
{% for player in players %}
    <!-- team name only once -->
    {% if forloop.first %}
        <h1>Players of {{player.team.name}}</h1>
    {% endif %}
    <!-- data of player here -->
{% endfor %}
```